# How do I make gasoline in Ark: Survival Evolved on PS4?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

So, im trying to make some things in my save. But I cant figure out how to get the fabricator to work. Ive got all the materials needed to make the items in the fabricator, but it won't let me craft them. Ive Googled it, ive checked the wiki, a bunch of other articles, and even watched some YouTube videos. I spent roughly 3 hours looking for the answer on here, and cant find it...
Everything ive seen says I need gasoline. Ok, but how do I get gasoline then? Everything I can find online seems outdated, or just tells you to put materials in the forge to make the gasoline, but the blueprint doesn't show up for gasoline. There's no engram, and it's not actually *in* the forge as a craftable thing. Does it work like the compost bin or the food preserver, where you just leave it there for a while and it automatically makes the gasoline? If so, how long do I have to wait? I need to make a refrigerator and an AC unit so I can preserve my food and properly cool eggs if they overheat during the incubation process, but I need polymer and computer chips for those...
Tl;dr: cant figure out how to make gasoline, how do I get it?

Comment: Oh, im dumb... I was getting the smithy confused with the refining forge. My bad!

Comment: I'd encourage you to write up an answer detailing what you've figured out, just in case someone else comes along in the future with a similar confusion!